# Inflater Get Compression Method

Tags: java

I have a file which is compressed.

Using the `Inflater` class, I'm able to decompress it but when I compress it again using `Deflater` both files are not identical.

I already tried changing the compression level to best...

```
public static String compress(byte[] rawData)
{
    Deflater compressor = new Deflater();

    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
            rawData.length);

    compressor.setInput(rawData);
    compressor.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
    compressor.finish();

    while (!compressor.finished())
    {
        outputStream.write(byteBuffer, 0,
                new Integer(compressor.deflate(byteBuffer)));
    }

    return new String(outputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

...and the result is much closer to the original.

Here's my Inflater code:

```
public static String decompress(byte[] compressed)
        throws DataFormatException
{
    Inflater decompressor = new Inflater();

    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
            compressed.length);

    decompressor.setInput(compressed);

    while (!decompressor.finished())
    {
        outputStream.write(byteBuffer, 0,
                new Integer(decompressor.inflate((byteBuffer))));
    }

    return new String(outputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

How do I figure out which options have initially been used in order to rebuild the original file from the decompressed one? My newly compressed file is not compliant.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to do that?

Comment: @Boann: I got a compressed file with scripts which I want to modify and rebuild. No details about it are given

Comment: ‎@‍user3764804 But why should it matter what precise compressor settings were used, so long as it can be decompressed by any compliant decompressor?

Comment: You realize that some compression algorithms change their behavior based on external factors such as CPU utilization or RAM usage. Also, some do a better job than others (often for a trade-off of one of the above). The only things that really should matter are that it can be decompressed and that it meets the required performance requirements.

Comment: @Dark Falcon: When I compress it, it isn't compliant. It is possible to replicate the same compression though.

Comment: `Using the Inflater class, I'm able to decompress it` Can we see the code for that?

Comment: How do you know it isn't compliant. I don't see you saying anything about the decompresser not being able to decompress it. That is what compliant means here. The only thing you mention is the file not being identical, which is not necessarily a problem.

Comment: @Thinkingcap: Code added

Dark Falcon: Well, I tried my compressed file with the system and it gave this error: `Ionic.Zlib.ZlibException: Bad state (oversubscribed literal/length tree)`. In Java this: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid literal/lengths set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect your problems are caused by this line:

```
return new String(outputStream.toByteArray());
```

The `String(byte[])` constructor converts bytes to characters using an unspecified platform-dependent character set which can arbitrarily corrupt binary data, because not all possible bytes correspond to valid characters. There is no guarantee that `new String(someBytes).getBytes()` equals `someBytes`. You should return the byte array instead.

Comment: Yes! :)
Converting to String messed things up, thanks a lot man!
Files are now identical.